# Computing JWS Signature for Google oAuth2 (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, rsa, sha256, oauth-2.0

I'm in the process of setting up server-to-server auth for my react app to be able to pull data from the Google Spreadsheet API without the user having to authenticate.

I'm going through the docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

I'm having an issue with this bit:

**`Sign the UTF-8 representation of the input using SHA256withRSA (also known as RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN with the SHA-256 hash function) with the private key obtained from the Google API Console. The output will be a byte array.`**

What would this look like using javascript?

I've got the private key from my Google API console, and i've got the UTF-8 representation of the input ready to go.

I'm just not sure how I go about signing it using SHA256withRSA with the private key.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you've got all the ingredients, now you just want to make the product!

Here's how you can sign input:

Use the crypto lib: https://github.com/thenativeweb/crypto2

Find the correct hashing algorithm (they are listed on there github) and away you go. Here is an example

```
crypto2.sign(YOUR_INPUT_HERE, your_private_key, (err, signature) => {
    console.log (signature); // View the contents
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately when I install crypto2 via NPM and try to require it within my app, it's causing an error during the build.

"SyntaxError: Unexpected token (3:6)" coming from /node_modules/crypto2/lib/crypto2.js

Comment: I ended up going with the Crypto over Crypto2 and was able to get it working using their documentation - thanks for steering me in the right direction!

Comment: Marking this as correct as the error I experienced was likely due to my own build process :)

Comment: Glad to hear! @JayChesterman I'm unsure why crypto 2 wouldn't be working, have u tried searching that particular bug on Google?

Comment: I did do some digging but was unable to find a resolution, I believe it has something to do with using Literalify as part of my build process.